# jQuery add text before final element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array:

```
var countryArray = [];
```

That I'm dynamically inserting values to with click events:

(on click...)

```
countryArray.push("Australia");
```

and then finally appending to a div for output:

```
$('#summary-countries').append(countryArray+'');
```

So my output could be:

```
Australia,United Kingdom,Finland,Japan.
```

Is there any way how I could insert some text so that it would output as the following:

```
Australia,United Kingdom,Finland **AND** Japan.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var countries;

if( countryArray.length > 1 ) { 
    var last = countryArray.pop();
    countries = countryArray.join(', ')+' and '+last;
}
else {
    countries = ''+countryArray;
}

$( '#summary-countries' ).append( countries );
```

Comment: `countryArray.join(', ')` would be preferable to `countryArray+''`

Comment: @Eric countryArray is guaranteed to have 0 or 1 elements at that point. I suppose `countries = countryArray.length ? countryArray[0] : '';` would be more legible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You are relying on the built-in serialization of arrays, when you call `.append(reasonsTravelling+'');`. This converts `reasonsTravelling` into a string, which, by default is a comma separated list.

You have to use a `for` loop instead and go through all the items in the array. Once you find that the iterator is `one before the last index`, use the "And" instead of ",".

This fiddle should explain my idea: http://jsfiddle.net/v76Bf/

Answer (score -1):

You can traverse through and array and find the last index and insert the text before the last value.

```
for (var i=0;i<countryArray.length;i++)
{
if(i==countryArray.length-1)
{
countryArray[i].join(,).push("And");
}
}
```